# Python : Splitting multidimensional lists

Tags: python, list, unicode, split

I have a list in the form of

```
[(u'a1', u'b1'),
 (u'a1', u'b2'),
 (u'c1', u'c2')]
```

I want it two be split into two lists/columns like

```
list1          list2    
[(u'a1',       [(u'b1'),
 (u'a1',       (u'b2'),
 (u'c1')]       (u'c2')]
```

Conversion of **unicode to string** would also help!

Also, in another case, I have list in the form of

```
[(('a', 'c'), -3), (('a', 'd'), -7), (('c', 'd'), -4)]
```

I need the input in the form of

```
('a','a','c')
('c','d','d')
(-3,-7,-4)
```

Any tips?

Comment: Your formatting makes things confusing, and your parenthesis are not closed nor do they form tuples where they are.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The second example:

```
>>> L = [(('a', 'c'), -3), (('a', 'd'), -7), (('c', 'd'), -4)]
>>> zip(*[(a[0], a[1], b) for a, b in L])
[('a', 'a', 'c'), ('c', 'd', 'd'), (-3, -7, -4)]
```

It first flattens each item and then transposes the list.

Answer (score 5):

You could create two new list using lists comprehension:

```
x=[(u'a1', u'b1'),
 (u'a1', u'b2'),
 (u'c1', u'c2')]

list1 = [i[0] for i in x]

list2 = [i[1] for i in x]
```

Comment: Bang on! got anything with `[(('a', 'c'), -3), (('a', 'd'), -7), (('c', 'd'), -4)]` into `('a','a','c')
('c','d','d')
(-3,-7,-4)` case?